# Eclipse: Cannot run program "cs-make": Launching failed

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, embedded, stm32, freertos

For the past week, i have been hunting a free development environment for STM32F1xx, which is supported by FreeRTOS. And no success yet :( .

Now I've found this: http://www.stf12.org/developers/ODeV.html

It's an Eclipse configuration for STM32 compiling and debugging, and there is a FreeRTOS demo too. Perfect!

So I downloaded a preconfigered version of eclipse and tried to compile a demo project to get this error:

```
Cannot run program "cs-make": Launching failed.
```

Depressing. Please help, i am very bad at configuring IDE's, compilers and linkers so this has to be newbie-friendly :)

Comment: It would appear that the "cs-make" program has either not yet been installed, or has moved to a different location from where it was on the system or point in time at which the authors of this setup found it.  For a start, you probably want to search your machine for it.  Generally speaking, you are going to need to become comfortable with troubleshooting and correcting issues like this if you want to do embedded development.  Such issues are routine with open-source tools and systems, but far from unknown (and sometimes much harder or even impossible to fix) on proprietary ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse project is configured for CodeSourcery toolchain. You need to install CodeSourcery compiler toolchain from: http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/codesourcery. Choose Lite Edition, ARM-NONE-EABI package. After the installation make sure you can start cs-make from command prompt (by typing it's name there). Generally, you want all toolchain programs to be accessible from command prompt, which implies that their installation path must be in system PATH variable.

P.S.
Make sure the path DOES NOT contain spaces like standard Windows programs directory "C:\Program Files", instead install the tools in a directory like "C:\arm-none-eabi", "C:\ARM_tools" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, thank you got it to work now!

And I ran into another problem too. When I tried to compile another error came up saying something like: "C:\Program is no file or directory". I Solved it by placing all compilers and OpenOCD in the root of my C-drive. I think it's because the make doesn't understand spaces in the make file, if anyone else get the same problem.